# Predestination and omniscience

Tags: jahannam, qadar, torture

God is Almighty and knows what is going to happen in the future. I watched this video by Shabir Ally: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRWfDUoYsFQ and it started confusing me. We can never truly know God's intentions or whether Hell is eternal or not, but I'm starting to think it isn't. I think it just seemed more logical to me. I read these questions and answers:
[Is there any sect in Islam that don't believe Hell is eternal?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/57522/is-there-any-sect-in-islam-that-dont-believe-hell-is-eternal)
[Are there any Islamic schools of thought that reject the literal hell?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/31276/are-there-any-islamic-schools-of-thought-that-reject-the-literal-hell)

They talk about ibn Arabi and I read there was someone else who had a view that it wasn't eternal too.

I've read somewhere that people will go to Hell eternally, because if they could live eternally they would sin eternally but then that leads to a question on the attributes of God because how is God *just* if someone is doomed to eternal torture. God could have not created them in the first place or just created another reality where he didn't have to suffer eternally. Yes, if God just sent whoever to Hell and Heaven straight away people would question so this is why life is a trial, but sent to eternal hell? 
Then I watched a video of where it says if God knows everything where is the test, but the answer still wasn't satisfying. Hell is supposed to cleanse us but eternal Hell is torture not cleansing. If sins on this Earth are finite then infinite punishment/torture can't be justified and you can't reconcile that idea with the idea that it's meant to cleanse us.

God is omniscient and predestines us so how is eternal Hell justified?

Edit: Just found another link which talks about the subject but still doesnt answer it:
[How can God create without determining the outcome?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7161/how-can-god-create-without-determining-the-outcome)

Comment: I apologise if I said anything rude because I know this can be very sensitive. Also, is it possible for you to answer my previous question as i havent really got an answer yet: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/60568/the-evidence-for-islam-being-true

Comment: If anyone has an answer, you can answer years late but please still answer.

Comment: You said "Hell is supposed to cleanse" but I don't think there is any evidence for it. Hell is a punishment, not cleansing.

Comment: @The Z  I daresay I agree with you

Comment: @TheZ even so that still doesnt answer the question

Comment: "If sins on this Earth are finite then infinite punishment/torture can't be justified" - Why not? Is the punishment and it's length decided based on the amount of sins you committed or on the type of sin you committed?

Comment: It contradicts the idea of a just God in and of itself but anyways saying that Hell is supposed to cleanse you of your actions or as said in the Quran (not exact words) but a payback for your deeds. How is payback for something limited unlimited. Its not payback its more and the idea itself is illogical and takes away charateristics of God which can not be done as it would contradict our whole faith in Islam as it is.