# Is it permissible to marry someone who dresses immodestly or is negligent in prayer if you can't find anyone else?

Tags: nikah, sex, clothing, alcohol, modesty

There are lots of married Muslim couples in the West but there is also a problem present for some of us.

In the West clothing is not as modest as it is in Muslim majority countries. Lots of women wear tight clothing, makeup etc and even young individuals are doing it. Its extremely rare to see someone dressed in the correct manner and I can say this with certainty its probably been over at least 3 months (corona may have played part but again there is social media). There are also women who smoke, drink, majority have relationships and lots have committed Zina (this is all from personally conversing with others and of course openly communicating about this). There are also numerous who dont pray and again this is the majority and I know because from majority one ive spoken to, texted etc (males arent an exception) this is just a recurring theme.

Ive read this: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/5208/neglecting-prayer-out-of-laziness and in it it says those who miss prayers are considered kaffir.

The things mentioned above don't cover the minor bad deeds that are done. Now for marriage i have read that you should marry a practicing Muslim and its really hard to find someone. If they are which I doubt I've found in a while then there may be an issue in appearance which could play an impact later. An alternative is moving countries but then there is a language barrier.

Barely anyone also asks for permission for a relationship first and usually get into a relationship first and later on ask about marriage. This is also something that isn't allowed to my understanding.

Is it permissible to marry someone who dresses immodestly or is negligent in prayer etc if you cannot find anyone else?

Even if you are allowed but have to try help them change their ways, what if they don't are you allowed to pursue the marriage?

Comment: To anyone reading I would appreciate if you attempted to answer two of my previous question that I am still looking for answers on: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/60601/predestination-and-omniscience and https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/60568/the-evidence-for-islam-being-true

Comment: What hinders you from marrying a modest Muslim girl as most religious Muslims do? I don't see only a problem here with the west, rather than with you.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Well calling me a problem simply because of preference is jsut wrong. As mentioned before I cant find any and its been months since I have seen one and even then there is an issue with physical attraction, personality etc. It isnt Tinder we cant just hookup in real life and have a night together and forget about it.

Comment: Why do you think it would be wise to marry someone immodest? If someone doesn't fear Allah and doesn't respect His Rights over her, why do you think she will be giving you your rights as a husband?

Comment: @Crimson Saying that someone wont give me rights as a husband simply because they arent terligious is wrong. Also you do not encessarily know their upbringing they may have been brought up in a non-practicing household. Again non of this answers the question

Comment: Why is it wrong? Do you really think someone who doesn't fear Allah and live according to it's rules cares about your Islamic rights as a husband? If she doesn't care about the religion, she could care less about any of the duties it obligates her as a wife.

Comment: @Crimson Thats just an assumption your making, if you have any evidence to back it up then very well (it still doesnt answer the question anyway).

Comment: I gave you a reasoning, and I am pretty sure it makes sense to you, but you're trying to act ignorant. Ironically, you make many assumptions and claims in your question with no backups at all other than "that's what I observed, so it's true" reasoning and you expect people to ignore them and answer you. That just a display of double standards.

Comment: Again are you a psychic? You dont know what I believe or think and I am not acting ignorant, I made those claims based off my personal experience and through my personal experience with others and witnessing the relationship of others I regard those claims you made as fallacious or you just being arrogant. Nowhere did I say its true I just aid its what I have observed and until I see the other side (which I am yet to see despite being on this case for probably years now) I am going to accept that claim.  If you arent going to answer my question stop wasting my time.